# Is there any way that I can distinguish between leaving the page(or close the browser) and reloading?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using signalr for real-time communication.
I want to do something when I leave the page or close the browser.
So I attached onclose event to the signalr.
But it's event is also fired when I refresh the page.
Is there any way that can distinguish between leaving page or refreshing the page?
I've tried this code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (e) => {
      const { type } = window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0];
      if (type === "reload") {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Chrome requires the returnValue property to be set
        e.returnValue = "";
      } else e.returnValue = "You are about leave the page"; */
    };

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, []);
```

But I think type is always "reload" and message is not the one I passed to e.returnValue.
it always shows this.

[image]

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
   const handleBeforeUnload = (e) => {
    const { type } = window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0];
    if (type === "reload") {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Chrome requires the returnValue property to be set
      e.returnValue = "";
    } else {
      e.returnValue = "You are about to leave the page";
    }
  };

  const handleUnload = () => {
    // Perform your cleanup or additional actions here
  };

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
    window.addEventListener("unload", handleUnload);

      return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
      window.removeEventListener("unload", handleUnload);
    };
    }, []);
```